# How to select max value faster from large size table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have query

```
SELECT max(ParameterID) FROM modelparam_ems
```

Table Name: `modelparam_ems`

No Of Rows: `9000`

It takes time to retrieve `max` value of `parameterId, ParameterId` in Unique value.

Output Time :

(Below row copied from Mysql Workbench).

```
13:51:15    SELECT max(ParameterID) FROM modelparam_ems 1 row(s) returned   0.109 sec / 0.000 sec
```

Comment: Execute `create index idx_modelparam_ems_parameterid on modelparam_ems(ParameterID);` if you haven't an index on it already and it will run almost lightning-fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. as TomBom Mentioned, you need to create an index on `ParameterID` column using this statement

   ```
   create index idx_modelparam_ems_parameterid on modelparam_ems(ParameterID);
   ```
2. If your `ParameterID` column is `AUTO_INCREMENT`,

   you can get your max id by getting the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value from the following query

   ```
   SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT-1
   FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE table_name = 'modelparam_ems'
   AND table_schema = 'YourDBName' ;
   ```

   If the engine is MyISAM and you are sure that there is no gap between two ids, you can find your max id by getting number of rows in the table as below. `ROWS` column contains the value for number of rows.

   ```
   EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM modelparam_ems;
   ```

   **Note that** In Innodb the value returned in rows is an estimation of total rows. So it is not as accurate as MyISAM.

**Disclaimer**

Option 2 may be both unreliable, and subjected to failure. Use it only if option 1 is not possible and you can tolerate the failure.

Comment: ParameterId is not auto incremented

Comment: then index it is, it might get a bit better if your ParameterID is `INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`

Comment: The 2nd suggestion is not safe. It may not give correct result. Rows can be deleted from tables, auto-increment may not be `1`, it may even be negative.

Comment: @ypercube when is it not safe? when we are inserting rows in Bulk?

Comment: (unsafe meaning: not correct result) I added 3 reasons above. Fourth reason: the table is empty.

Comment: There are many reasons why `AUTO_INCREMENT-1` might not exist, etc.  Do not use that!

Comment: @RickJames If the solo purpose and use of indexing the column is to get the max id, it is an expensive option. One may use alternative by taking some risk of failure. And I did mentioned the risk in there. so it comes down to how exact your value should be or how much risk can you take.